# IF MAIS SIMPLES NO REACT JS PARA EVITAR REPETIÇÃO DE CÓDIGO

Tags: react, material-ui

Eu estou iniciando minha caminhada no react e estou fazendo um clone do youtube. Eu cheguei numa parte onde não sei se o que eu fiz é uma  boa ou má prática que gostaria de ajuda de vocês. Seguinte.

Eu tenho um componente que ao ser chamado PODE ou NÃO ser um botão.

Então quando ele é chamado eu o chamo assim:

```
<SideMenuOptions isButton={true} itemIcon={<HomeIcon/>} itemText={'Ínicio'} />
```

Se o boleano de botão for "TRUE" significa que ele é um botão, se não, é apenas um campo de texto.

Agora abrindo o código do componente SideMenuOptions nós encontramos:

```
function isButton(isButton, itemIcon, itemText) {
if (isButton) {
    return (
        <ListItem button>
            <ListItemIcon>{itemIcon}</ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText>{itemText}</ListItemText>
        </ListItem>
    )
}
return (
    <ListItem>
        <ListItemIcon>{itemIcon}</ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText>{itemText}</ListItemText>
    </ListItem>
)}

export default function SideMenuOptions(props) {
return (
    <>
        {isButton(props.isButton, props.itemIcon, props.itemText)}
    </>
)}
```

Ou seja, o componente SideMenuOptions returna uma função, que ao executada ela verifica se a propriedade isButton é verdadeira ou não.
Para um item ser um botão, basta eu informar no  a propriedade Button, mas ela necessariamente precisa ter aqueles childrens.

Eu achei que esse ctrl + c ctrl + v muita repetição de código. Teria uma solução mais elaborada para o problema? Quero muito a ajuda dos senhores nisso!

Answer (score 0):

No JSX, escrever um atributo omitindo o seu valor, é equivalente a dar a ele o valor `true`. Ou seja, `<ListItem button />` é equivalente a `<ListItem button={true} />`.

Assim, tudo que é necessário no seu código é fazer

```js
export default function SideMenuOptions({ isButton, itemIcon, itemText }) {
    return (
        <ListItem button={isButton}>
            <ListItemIcon>{itemIcon}</ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText>{itemText}</ListItemText>
        </ListItem>
    );
}
```